@pytest.mark.parametrize for function that returns two values
I have a function that takes a pandas DataFrame (it is important that this specific DataFrame, that goes as an argument into the function, has no column names) and produces a DataFrame with column names and a list of column names. Now, I want to test it with:
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test, ex1, ex2",
    [
        (pd.DataFrame(list(zip([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]))),
        pd.DataFrame({'Col1': [1, 2], 'Col2': [3, 4], 'Col3': [5, 6]}),
        ['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']),
    ])
def test_col_names(test, ex1, ex2):
    pdt.assert_frame_equal(packagename.modulename.col_names(test), (ex1, ex2))

But when I try to run it I get this error:
FAILED test1.py::test_col_names[test0-ex10-US10] - AssertionError: DataFrame Expected type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, found <class 'tuple'> instead.

Can anyone assist me with this problem?
I tried changing the brackets and how I define DataFrames here, but I think I am missing something else. I expected a pass on this test.

pdt.assert_frame_equal should be used to compare two dataframes, and you pass a tuple (ex1, ex2), consisting of a dataframe and a list. Changing brackets would not help. Refactor you test into two tests or two subsequent asserts, one to check dataframe body and another column names. To switch off the column name check you can use
check_names=false https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html#pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal
